# Getting empty string after parsing bash associative array to json using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a bash associative array containing dynamic data like:

```
declare -A assoc_array=([cluster_name]="cpod1" [site_name]="ppod1" [alarm_name]="alarm1")
```

I have to create the JSON data accordingly.

```
{
"name": "cluster_name",
"value": $assoc_array[cluster_name],
"regex": False
}
{
"name": "site_name",
"value": $assoc_array[site_name],
"regex": False
}
{
"name": "alert_name",
"value": $assoc_array[alert_name],
"regex": False
}
```

I have used the following code for it:

```
for i in "${!assoc_array[@]}"; do
    echo $i
    alarmjsonarray=$(echo ${alarmjsonarray}| jq --arg name "$i" \
                                                --arg value "${alarm_param[$i]}" \
                                                --arg isRegex "False" \
                                                '. + [{("name"):$name,("value"):$value,("isRegex"):$isRegex}]')
done
echo "alarmjsonarray" $alarmjsonarray
```

I am getting empty string from it. Can you please help me in it?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre] that's complete enough to copy-and-paste without changes? Your current code requires `cluster_name`, `site_name`, etc to have values already.

Comment: Also, `echo ${alarmjsonarray}` is in general an antipattern; see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` prints something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: okay.. let me edit my question for you...

Comment: (and in general, I'd suggest writing your code to call `jq` _only once_ instead of calling it in a loop; you can stream your data on input to a single copy of jq and let it turn that into an array).

Comment: Will it iterative, without using loop? @CharlesDuffy

Comment: By default, jq transforms each value on stdin with the expression given. You can also bypass that and write an expression that uses `inputs` explicitly.

Comment: What guarantees do you have about values in your strings? Do you need to worry about them containing newlines? What about NULs? Are there other sigils like tabs you can safely use?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am checking already about newlines and NULs before putting it into the array. I have changed the question for it. Please let me know the correct code. I am new to jq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the ASCII record separator character `\x1e` can't occur in your data (and given your assertions that newlines will never be present), one way to handle this would be:

```sh
for key in "${!assoc_array[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\x1e%s\n' "$key" "${assoc_array[$key]}"
done | jq -Rn '
[
  inputs |
  split("\u001e") | .[0] as $key | .[1] as $value |
  {"name": $key, "value": $value, "regex": false}
]'
```

...feel free to change `\x1e` to a different character (like a tab) that can never exist, as appropriate.

Comment: Can we store the output of it into some variable, as I have take var alarmjsonarray?

Comment: `result=$(for ...; done | jq ...)` will store the stdout of the entire pipeline in `result`.

Comment: I used the following code: 
  alarmjsonarray=$(for key in "${!assoc_array[@]}"; do
                    printf '%s\x1e%s\n' "$key" "${assoc_array[$key]}"
                   done | jq -Rn '
                   [
                    inputs |
                    split("\u001e") | .[0] as $key | .[1] as $value |
                    {"name": $key, "value": $value, "regex": false}
                   ]')
  
  echo "alarmjsonarray" $alarmjsonarray 
and I got the following result: 
alarmjsonarray []

Comment: I'd need a [mre] to be able to address any issues -- tested this before posting it, works for me..

Comment: @AadhiVerma, ...see the exact code I tested and its output at https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/7621542a383893e94798c0c9cc970abb

Comment: I got the result now, why it is enclosed in [], when it was expected to be only like : 
{
    "name": "alarm_name",
    "value": "alarm1",
    "regex": false
  },
  {
    "name": "cluster_name",
    "value": "cpod1",
    "regex": false
  },
  {
    "name": "site_name",
    "value": "ppod1",
    "regex": false
  }

Comment: @AadhiVerma, if you don't want it enclosed in `[]` just take that out; take out the `[` and the `]` at the beginning and end of the jq expression. You can also take out both the `-n` argument and the `inputs |`.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you update your github code for that?

Comment: Done. (BTW, the reason I put the `[]`s in was I saw you using them in your original code).

Comment: Okay... So there was just doing hint ad trial to get the desired the output. Now the output you got, is not comma separated. Desired output is like : 
{
  "name": "alarm_name",
  "value": "alarm1",
  "regex": false
},
{
  "name": "cluster_name",
  "value": "cpod1",
  "regex": false
},
{
  "name": "site_name",
  "value": "ppod1",
  "regex": false
}
thanks in advance... You saved me today, its just last modification I need from you.

Comment: It's not JSON anymore if you don't have the starting `[` and `]` but still have commas. I'm not willing to help someone create data that is not valid JSON.

Comment: So let it be with JSON only, is there any way to make "regex":False instead of false?

Comment: `False` isn't a valid JSON literal. Is this really being parsed as a Python literal, maybe, instead of as JSON?

Comment: To be clear, you can definitely have `"regex": "False"`, but you can't have `"regex": False`. See the format spec at https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: So this JSON will be passed to ansible-playbook and from there it will be passed to some API which uses python.

Comment: If the API is _written in_ Python, but _expects to read_ JSON, then it should be `false`. Only if the API accepts Python literals instead of wanting JSON at all is `False` correct -- and if that's your scenario, I'd want to _write your code in Python_ and use `repr()` instead of any `json`-library thing to dump the results.

Comment: Thanks @charlesduffy this code is working fine with me, only issue with me they need the --arg format of JQ as I have specified in question. Otherwise the code you have written here for creating JSON is working absolutely fine with me.  So can you edit your answer or add another answer with the expected format?

Comment: `--arg` prevents you from reusing a single instance, since to pass in new values to the existing variables, you need a new instance of jq. In this context, it's actually a bad idea; it means your code _has_ to be inefficient. Why do they "need" that format so badly?

Comment: (To be clear, I don't see your question anywhere describing using `--arg` as a requirement, merely as the existing implementation; the whole point of asking a SO question is to get advice on how to improve your existing implementation to resolve an issue. If there's a requirement, explain the reasoning, and we can try to figure out how to satisfy it without the performance impact).

Comment: thanks was your efforts. I found the issue with my code. And your code was also looking good. I kept it with me for future use. I am marking your answer as correct answer. Thanks for being kind.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A assoc_array=([cluster_name]="cpod1" [site_name]="ppod1" [alarm_name]="alarm1")
for i in "${!assoc_array[@]}"; do
  alarmjsonarray=$(echo "${alarmjsonarray:-[]}" |
                   jq --arg name "$i" \
                      --arg value "${assoc_array[$i]}" \
                      --arg isRegex "False" \
                      '. + [{("name"):$name,("value"):$value,("isRegex"):$isRegex}]')
done
echo "alarmjsonarray" "$alarmjsonarray"
```

array was supposed to be initialized before using it. I thought in bash, scope is there out of block also.
Its more simpler way to generate json from bash associative array.

Comment: Do make sure you're quoting your expansions -- if you run your code through http://shellcheck.net/, it'll point out the places where this needs to be done. Otherwise, for example, a string `" * "` in your file can be changed to `" a.txt b.txt c.txt "` (substituting filenames in your current directory).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated my code accordingly. You had been very helpful n kind to me.